# Array initialization and the "new" keyword

Tags: java, arrays

Syntax aside, is there any difference between the following two statements?

```
String[] str = { "test" };
```

and

```
String[] str = new String[] {"test"};
```

Comment: You can't break the first into multiple statements. That's all.

Comment: No, this is just a shortcut syntax. And you can check by seeing the bytecode produced by this two snippet of code.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no difference. Except if you want to pass it to the method

```
methodWhichAcceptsArray({"a", "b"}); //won't compile
methodWhichAcceptsArray(new String[] {"a", "b"}); //ok
```

Answer (score 4):

Let's see:

```
// String[] str1 = { "test" };
   0: iconst_1      
   1: anewarray     #16                 // class java/lang/String
   4: dup           
   5: iconst_0      
   6: ldc           #18                 // String test
   8: aastore       
   9: astore_1      

// String[] str2 = new String[] {"test"};
  10: iconst_1      
  11: anewarray     #16                 // class java/lang/String
  14: dup           
  15: iconst_0      
  16: ldc           #18                 // String test
  18: aastore       
  19: astore_2
```

As you can see, they compile to identical bytecodes.

Note that outside intiailizations you generally have to use the second form.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

```
String[] str = { "test" };
```

Will be interperated by the JVM as

```
String[] str = new String[] {"test"};
```